# Why is there a distinct "inter-thread happens before" relation defined in ISO/IEC 14882:2011?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-model

§ 1.10.11 of ISO/IEC 14882:2011 (C++ 11) defines the "inter-thread happens before" relation between evaluations, whose only difference from the "happens before" relation in § 1.10.12 is that A happens before B if A is sequenced before B but that is not sufficient for A inter-thread happens before B. Why is "inter-thread happens before" important enough to warrant a separate definition?

A note in § 1.10.11 suggests that "inter-thread happens before" doesn't allow evaluations whose only relation is "sequenced before" in part

> to permit “inter-thread happens before” to be transitively closed

What does that mean? I know what a transitive closure is, and I know what it means for a set to be closed over some operation, but I've never heard of "transitively closed" and both Google and context are failing me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Inter-thread happens before" is defined purely for exposition. Note how "happens before" is defined as "sequenced before or inter-thread happens before", and the notion of "inter-thread happens before" is not used for anything else. "Sequenced before" describes evaluations happening on the same thread, "inter-thread happens before" applies to evaluations happening on different threads; "happens before" combines the two.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Any idea what the "transitively closed" remark means? Probably I should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @SheaLevy Do you have an answer for this question by now? If not, I would create a new question and post the link here, since I'm also interested in this topic.

Answer (score 2):

The "transitively closed" remark simply means that the relation is transitive: if A inter-thread happens before B and B inter-thread happens before C, then A inter-thread happens before C.

That property doesn't hold if "sequenced before" alone qualifies as "inter-thread happens before" because of the first exclusion (of sequences ending in "dependency-ordered before" followed by "sequenced before").

This also means that "happens before" is not transitive; if A happens before B and B happens before C, it doesn't necessarily follow that A happens before C.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I think this should have been the accepted answer since the other one doesn't actually explain why the transitivity would not hold if inter-thread happens before could be composed purely of sequenced-befores.